# How do you select a random member id from a server? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I have tried a lot of stuff and researched as much as I can, I can't find anything that works or I can get inspiration from. Anything that I find doesn't work and I need help.
I just want to get a random member from id (maybe create an array of the ids).
This is the closest I have gotten/best thing I can think of:

```
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
for (const [, member] of members) {
  console.log(member.id);
};
```

member.id gets all the ids of the users in the server but I don't know what else to do with that(like make it into an array). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [`.random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=random) on the members collection like so:

```
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
const randMember = members.random(); 
console.log(randMember);
```

If you want an array of random members, you can pass a number into the `.random()` method to specify how many random members you want, eg: `.random(5)` will give 5 random members.

Comment: That works however I still have no clue on how to get the id, sorry. I get a random user but don't know how to get a random **id**. I tried:

`
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
const randMember = members.random().id; 
console.log(randMember);
`

Sorry if I am doing this incorrectly, I am trying to get the id out of what this gives me however using this code returns undefined.

Comment: actually, sorry. Using message.channel.send tags a random user, which is what I wanted. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @FatPotato Oh ok, no worries, I don't know too much about the discord api myself so no need to be sorry :). I was going to suggest to maybe try `const [, {id}] = members.random()` as a fix to your first comment, but if you've got it working then that's good (you can add an answer to your own question if you think it will help others in the future)

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Stack overflow too so I don't know much about how to ask questions or how to put comments in a *proper* way.  Anyways, this helped, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here, `members` is a Collection where the member IDs are keys. You can use the
[`.randomKey()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=randomKey) method to get a random ID. So, your line might be `const randomId = members.randomKey(1)` or something like that.